# linux + how to convert variable to array

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, array, bash-array

we want to set variable that includes words as array

```
folder_mount_point_list="sdb sdc sdd sde sdf sdg"
ARRAY=( $folder_mount_point_list )
```

but when we want to print the first array value we get all words

```
echo ${ARRAY[0]}
sdb sdc sdd sde sdf sdg
```

expected results

```
echo ${ARRAY[0]}
sdb

echo ${ARRAY[1]}
sdc
```

how to convert variable to array?

Comment: Can not reproduce. What's the value of `$IFS`?

Comment: we not set this value in my bash script

Comment: And if you do add `IFS=$' \t\n'` to your script?

Comment: ok now its works , can I do  unset IFS after ARRAY=( $folder_mount_point_list )

Comment: Why would you want to unset `IFS` instead of keeping it at its? Unsetting `IFS` has the same effect as setting it like `IFS=$' \t\n'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you have (maybe unintentionally) changed the important shell variable `IFS` in the script. Restoring it to its usual value or unsetting it (i.e. activating its default value) solves the problem:

```
IFS=$' \t\n'
```

or

```
unset IFS
```

Comment: On my system unsetting `IFS` doesn't restore its default value. I cannot find such statement in bash manual either. Where did you get if from?

Comment: @jimmij Not "restore" in the sense that `$IFS` contains non-empty data after being unset but after unsetting `IFS` bash behaves like `IFS` having its default value.

Comment: @jimmij Search in bash manual for `If IFS is unset, or its value is exactly <space><tab><newline>,`. An unset IFS is functionally equivalent to the default, not equal though, as `var=IFS` sets var to null, not <space><tab><newline>.